# Bulk data insertion and updating from one db server to another db server

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nosql, database-migration, sqlbulkcopy

I have some set of tables which has 20 million records in a postgres server. As of now i m migrating some table data from one server to another server using insert and update queries with dependent tables in functions. It takes around 2 hours even after optimizing the query. I need a solution to migrate the data faster by using mongodb or cassandra. How?

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your updates and inserts into a file and then load the file. I understand Postgresql will optimise loading the file contents. It's always worked for me although I haven't used that quantity.

Comment: As of now we are using some procedures to move the data from one server to another based on the logic given by devleopers. But couldnt find any efficient way to move them atleast lesser than 10 minutes